# Ordering Spring proxies without AspectJ

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

```
@Service
@Transactional
public CarService {

   @Autowired private CarRepository carRepository;

   @Cachable("cars")
   public List<Car> getCars() {
      return carRepository.getAll();
   }
}
```

Suppose I have a code like this, where both `@Transactional` and `@Cachable` are presented. How can I guarantee that proxy chain spring will go through will be `proxyForCache`-`proxyForTransaction`? I.e. transaction won't be created, if my application already has cached result. I've seen a lot of examples, where people offer to implement `Ordered` interfaface on a class-level, namely, on `@Aspect` level. But problem is we don't use AspectJ in our project. Is there any way to order spring proxies without creating additional classes or at least using of AspectJ?

Comment: You can't. These need to be implemented in separate classes or else the proxy will not work.

Comment: I am not a Spring user, but neither the Javadoc for `@Order` nor for `@Ordered` show any hint about them being tied to Spring AOP. BTW, AspectJ does not use those annotations because AJ is independent of Spring and has its own ordering mechanism (`declare precedence` in native syntax and `@DeclarePrecedence` in annotation style). Anyway, chances are that you can use the order annotations independently of Spring AOP. But this is just an educated guess, a vague idea. Check it out if you like. The documentation mentions `@Order` for ordering event listeners and collections, for example.